# XML - how to sort file on one attribute?

Tags: xml, sorting

I have XML(very huge file) and I would like to get output based on SORTING of attribute(column) value `contact_name`. Is this possible using some tool or with coding?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sms.xsl"?>
<smses count="4">

 <sms address="+381642" subject="null" contact_name="C" />
 <sms address="+3816424" subject="null" contact_name="A" />
 <sms address="+3816427" subject="null" contact_name="B" />
</smses>
```

sms.xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:user="http://android.riteshsahu.com">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
      <head>
          <style type="text/css">
          body 
          {
            font-family:arial,sans-serif;
            color:#000;
            font-size:13px;
            color:#333;
          }
          table 
          {
            font-size:1em;
            margin:0 0 1em;
            border-collapse:collapse;
            border-width:0;
            empty-cells:show;
          }
          td,th 
          {
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            padding:6px 12px;
            text-align:left;
            vertical-align:top;
            background-color:inherit;
          }
          th 
          {
            background-color:#dee8f1;
          }
          </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      <h2>SMS Messages</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="smses/sms">
         <xsl:sort select="contact_name" data-type="text"/>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:if test="@type = 1">
            Received
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@type = 2">
            Sent
            </xsl:if>
          </td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@address"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@contact_name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@date"/><br/><xsl:value-of select="@readable_date"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@body"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your XSLT file, `sms.xsl`, you can do an [`<xsl:sort>`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp) using `@` to reference an attribute, like this...

```
<xsl:sort select="@contact_name"/>
```

**Note:** positioning is important, it needs to be within an `<xsl:for-each>` or `<xsl:apply-templates>`. So just insert the above line directly after the start of the `<xsl:for-each>` in your `sms.xsl` file...

```
<xsl:for-each select="smses/sms">
  <xsl:sort select="@contact_name"/> <!-- new line -->
```

Comment: please sorry but I never done with XSLT.. how to run that in what application? please can you give me the full description..sorry for this but really do not know anything about that...

Comment: The XML is already referencing an XSLT file: sms.xsl so this seems like a good place to do the sort. Can you post some or all of the that XSLT file?

Comment: I updated it. what exactly line should I change. thank you for efforts I suppose we are near of the solution?

Comment: yes I added you can see it in my new update. But when I reopen XML file nothing happens. Do I need some update,refresh...? both files are in the same folder

Comment: Are you opening the XML file in a web browser? And if yes, which one? Also, do you want the output file to also be XML or you just want them sorted in the HTML?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30641/discussion-between-davmos-and-ja-jaaaa)

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax of sorting in XML

```
<xsl:sort select="expression"
lang="language-code"
data-type="text|number|qname"
order="ascending|descending"
case-order="upper-first|lower-first"/>
```

Before that you need to know the XSTL formatting . See example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp)

Secondly you have use `<xsl:sort select="contact_name" data-type="text"/>` 
in XSL  file of XML

Finally here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:user="http://android.riteshsahu.com">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
      <head>
          <style type="text/css">
          body 
          {
            font-family:arial,sans-serif;
            color:#000;
            font-size:13px;
            color:#333;
          }
          table 
          {
            font-size:1em;
            margin:0 0 1em;
            border-collapse:collapse;
            border-width:0;
            empty-cells:show;
          }
          td,th 
          {
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            padding:6px 12px;
            text-align:left;
            vertical-align:top;
            background-color:inherit;
          }
          th 
          {
            background-color:#dee8f1;
          }
          </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      <h2>SMS Messages</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="smses/sms">
        <!-- Sorting added here -->
       <xsl:sort select="contact_name" data-type="text"/>             
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:if test="@type = 1">
            Received
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@type = 2">
            Sent
            </xsl:if>
          </td>  
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@address"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@contact_name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@date"/><br/><xsl:value-of select="@readable_date"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@body"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you but where to put that code in XSL file? I updated my question with XSL file. please tell me where to put that code? thank you

Comment: I have already added the sorting in the above code. Just use this to generate the xml . The output the filed will be sorted.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with new SMS.XSL file. I entered new row in XSL file. But when I reopen XML file nothing is changed? What am I doing wrong? Do I need some kind of refresh or...?